# Adding a subview to a UICollectionViewCell that takes up entire cell frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to simply add a UIView to a UICollectionViewCell that takes up the entire cell's frame. The code I have now only displays a single cell in the top left corner (I suspect each cell is getting layer out on top of each other). How exactly can I do this?

I plan on subclassing UIView later so as to customize the view that I am adding to the cell. I don't want to subclass UICollectionViewCell however based on the way I will be using it.

```
#pragma mark - Collection view data source

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 6;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIView *menuItem = [[UIView alloc] init];
    menuItem.frame = cell.frame;
    menuItem.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [cell addSubview:menuItem];

    return cell;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath; {
    return CGSizeMake(60, 60);
}
```

Comment: could you change menuItem.frame = cell.frame to menuItem.frame = cell.bounds

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'll need to use `bounds`, not `frame`.  If you don't know the difference between the two or why this matters, you should read up on this and get comfortable with it before going further:

```
menuItem.frame = cell.bounds;
```

You'll also want to set an autoresizing mask, since the cell won't initially be at the correct size:

```
menuItem.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

And, really, you should be adding this to the cell's `contentView` property:

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:menuItem];
menuItem.frame = cell.contentView.bounds;
```

That said, if you plan on adding lots of subviews to `menuItem`, I recommend subclassing UICollectionViewCell instead of trying to build it in your `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` method.  It will be much easier to control if the layout and setup is encapsulated in a different class, and you can respond to height / width changes by overriding `layoutSubviews`.

Comment: Ok maybe your are right. Thank you for all the help I think I will just do it by subclassing UICollectionViewCell as you suggested.

Comment: Great tip with autoresizing mask... i have been trying to solve that problem (incorrect sizing initially) for a LONG while now..thanks!

Comment: I'm now having issues with the reusable cell... if I add a subview to cell number 1, then iOS reuses that and it appears in cell 17 or 18. Any solutions?

Comment: @script kitty that’s how table cells work… if you add a view it will stay there until you change or remove it

Comment: I ended up cleaning up the view in the prepareForReuse method. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

You should only interact with the cell's `contentView` in this case.

```
UIView *menuItem = [UIView new];
menuItem.frame = cell.contentView.bounds;
menuItem.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
[cell.contentView addSubview:menuItem];
```

Answer (score 0):

It's Swift version.

```
let menuItem = UIView.init()
menuItem.frame = cell.bounds
menuItem.backgroundColor = .green
cell.contentView.addSubview(menuItem)
menuItem.frame = cell.contentView.bounds
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5 Apple doc:

1. var contentView: UIView
   *The main view to which you add your cell’s custom content.*
   *When configuring a cell, you add any custom views representing your cell’s content to this view. The cell object places the content in
   this view in front of any background views.*
2. var backgroundView: UIView?
   *The view that is displayed behind the cell’s other content.*
   *Use this property to assign a custom background view to the cell. The background view is placed behind the content view and its frame
   is automatically adjusted so that it fills the bounds of the cell.*

Example:

```
let template = UIView()
self.backgroundView = template
template.layer.cornerRadius = 10
template.backgroundColor = .white
```